# JavaScript regexp parsing an array of URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

## String

`url(image1.png), url('image2.png'), url("image3.png")`

Note the `'` and `"` delimiters. It would be nice to handle them as well, but I'm happy if the first form is captured.

## Result

`var results = 'image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png';`

## How?

I would like to use regular expressions in javascript to parse a string that is used as the CSS property of an element with multiple backgrounds. The aim is to get the url of the images that are put in the background of the element using CSS.

See more: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/fcx9x59r/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/url\(([^"']+?)\)|'([^'"]+?)'\)|"([^'"]+?)"\)/g
```

Try this.Grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qQ3kG7/1

Comment: I like your solution for its brevity and the use of Regex101 website. However this parses the following string `url(image1.png), url('image2.png"), url('image3.png")` too. Depends on how you look at it this can be a bug or a feature. Can we fix that?

Comment: Yes this last one is the best. Can you put that in your answer above?

Answer (score 2):

For this particular string `[^'"()]+(?=['")])` seems to work fine:

```js
css = "url(image1.png), url('image2.png'), url(\"image3.png\")";

m = css.match(/[^'"()]+(?=['")])/g)
document.write(m)
```

In the general case, you have to resort to a loop, because JS doesn't provide a way to return all matching groups from a single call:

```js
css = "url(image1.png), something else, url('image2.png'), url(\"image3.png\")";

urls = []
css.replace(/url\(['"]*([^'")]+)/g, function(_, $1) { urls.push($1) });

document.write(urls)
```

Comment: I thought `String.prototype.match` exactly returns all matches (if the regexp has the `g` option).

Comment: It works but I didn't understand that `(?=[` part. Can you explain a little more? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexStack is this the regex you want? It won't work in many cases. It would also match the string `foo` in `"foo)`

Comment: @AlexStack: `?=` is a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Basically, it reads "match ... when followed by...".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var results = str.match(/url\(['"]?[^\s'")]+['"]?\)/g)
.map(function(s) {
    return s.match(/url\(['"]?([^\s'")]+)['"]?\)/)[1];
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yw3n2aaw/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below code also.

```
> var s = 'url(image1.png), url(\'image2.png\'), url("image3.png")';
undefined
> var re = /url\((["'])?((?:(?!\1).|[^'"])*?)\1\)/g;
undefined
> var matches = [];
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(s)) != null) {
......... matches.push(m[2]);
......... }
3
> console.log(matches)
[ 'image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png' ]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xT4dS2/1)

Comment: would be great to do all of it in just one regexp. (no while loop)

Comment: Why do you need to do it in one regexp?

Comment: Because it's smaller and probably faster.